# iOS - what exactly should all the image names be in order to work with the retina display?

Tags: ios, ios5

I just went through all the images, and added images with the name original_name@2x.png so that there would be each image copy for the retina display.

But I have 4 images that have sort of strange names. For example:

```
Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png
Default-Landscape~ipad.png
Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png
Default-Portrait~ipad.png
```

and I am not sure if xCode added the ~ipad part to those names, or why they are like this. It seems a bit awkward naming.

What should those image names be? Should I switch the @2x in the names right to the left of the .png?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The paths you have listed are correct. The tilde suffixes like `~ipad` specify that the files should only be used on that particular device. See the [App-Related Resources](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html) documentation for more information. The general pattern for resource filenames is:

```
<basename>-<scale_modifier><device_modifier>.png
```

Default.png files can also support a scheme modifier although you probably don't need this. The only currently supported scale modifier is `@2x` and the device modifiers are `~ipad` and `~iphone`.

So taking one of your examples, the `Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png` file will only be used on retina (`@2x`) iPad (`~ipad`) devices.

Answer (score 1):

Check [Apple's link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1686.html) for default name of different files. You just need to place files with these default name if your app is universal.

Comment: would you know if its equally ok to have a name like icon.png and Icon.png where the only difference is that the I is capitalized.

Comment: iOS-Filesystem is case-sensitive