# Xcode - is it ok if I made a group for my image files and they are not at the base of the project?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5

I am reading the instructions here for the correct file setup for submitting the app to the app store: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html

in there there is a phrase like: "Like all other icon files, the iTunesArtwork image file must reside at the top level of your app bundle. "

But for organization sake, I made a group, and placed all the image files in root/src/img group.  Is that ok? Or should I specifically move all the image files to the root or the project?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is OK. When you place resources into a group, Xcode will copy them all into the root of your application when it builds it.

Comment: thank you - I'll accept in a few minutes when SO allows it.  By the way, I also have a question here that I am confused with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371158/ios-what-exactly-should-all-the-image-names-be-in-order-to-work-with-the-retin ...would you by any chance know about those naming conventions as well?

Comment: I happened to see that question as well, but this is not the place to discuss it.

Comment: you mean because it is not strictly a programming question, but more about images?

Comment: I just mean you shouldn't talk about other unrelated questions here.